# Cannot write accents in TextInput

Tags: apache-flex, internationalization, flex4

i'm doing the maintenance of a flex application and i have a form to create new items:

```
<mx:FormItem id="frmName"
            width="100%"
            label="{Translate.getInstance().translateWords.name}"
            required.edit="true"
            required.new="true"
            required.view="false">
            <s:Label id="name_l"
                width="100%" height="23"
                text="{ myProgramVO.program_name }"
                maxDisplayedLines="0"
                lineBreak="toFit"
                includeIn="view"/>
            <s:TextInput id="name_ti"
                width="100%" height="23"
                maxChars="100"
                maxChars.edit="100"
                maxChars.new="100"
                text="{ myProgramVO.program_name }"
                includeIn="edit,new"/>
</mx:FormItem>
```

I don't know why, but i cannot write characters with accents when i'm creating a new program, but i can when i'm editing a program. And does not seem an unicode problem because i can type `ñ` without any problem.

The mxml file has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and the file is the same for item edition.

Can somebody guide me in the right direction?

PS: If anybody needs more code just ask for it and i'll paste in pastebin or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it seems that there's nothing wrong with my code, it seem a problem with focus when mix html and swf.

When i try to create a new program, i need to mix html and flex, but when i edit the program there's no html code, and works well.

I got the problem only in linux (flash version 11.2), in windows (version 11.8) works perfectly, so seems a problem has been fixed

Thanks anyway guys :)